# RecyclerView - how to get position only on drag and on drop?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, rx-java2

The main usage of my `RecyclerView` is to change the order of items. What's more, after order changes, I need to get data about the position from where drag started and where it was dropped(finished).

I've already implemented `ItemTouchHelper.Callback()` and covered it with interface, works great but the only problem is how to get only FIRST and LAST position of the item.

I haven't found any solution using `ItemTouchHelper`, tried combining `onSelectedChanged` and `clearView` but it doesn't work. Also, I'm using `Subjects` from `RxJava2` to push the value but haven't found solution by using any kind of filter operator.

```
override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
    adapter.onItemMoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition)
    return true
}

private fun swapItems(positionFrom: Int, positionTo: Int) {
    Collections.swap(myList, positionFrom, positionTo)

    myList.forEachIndexed { index, myObject -> myListUpdated.add(myObject.copy(index = index)) }
    myListSubject.onNext(myListUpdated.toList())

    notifyItemMoved(positionFrom, positionTo)
}
```

At this moment I'm getting every swapped position from `onMove`(so from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3, from 3 to 4). I would like to achieve from 1 to 4, without the middle steps.